# How to add two lists in haskell?

Tags: haskell

how can I add for example [1,2,3] to [5,4,6] to return [6,6,8]
This is what I have so far:

```
func1 :: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]
func1 x y = [a+b|a<-x,b<-y]
```

Should I try and remove the elements that I don't want or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `zipWith`. In particular `func1 x y = zipWith (+) x y`. You can "eta reduce" to remove those extra parameters as well: `func1 = zipWith (+)`. This is the most efficient form I can think of.

Your current method doesn't work because `[a+b | a <- x, b <- y]` forms two nested loops, one over the `x`es and one inside it over the `y`s. This is the nature of list comprehensions and it's based on [Set Builder Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). One way to read it is "for each a from x, for each b from y, give me `(a + b)`" while we actually want to run through `x` and `y` together.

Comment: There's also a language extension called `ParallelListComp` (parallel list comprehensions) that allows you to write `func1` almost as given in the question: `func1 x y = [ a + b | a <- x | b <- y ]`

Comment: if the lists are not of the same length zipWith discards  the rest. Try this:
`zipSum (a : as) (b : bs) = a + b : zipSum as bs`
`zipSum as [] = as`
`zipSum [] bs = bs`

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is zipWith:

```
zipWith (+) [1,2,3][5,4,6]
```

Comment: So the same thing as what was already said 5 hours earlier?

Comment: I thought it appropriate to give an answer numerically exact to the stated question.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum' :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
sum' xs ys = map (uncurry (+)) $ zip xs ys
```

You can combine the above `map` and `zip` into a single function `zipWith` as `zipWith f xs ys = map (uncurry f) $ zip xs ys`.

Comment: this shows that `zipWith` is just a kind of `map` itself.

Comment: @WillNess In fact ML languages tend to call it `map2`.